# Check if polygon falls inside other polygon with 2 layers

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql, spatial-join, function

I have two polygons layers with SRID 4326, indexed in a PostGIS database. Layer 1 is a country layer. I want to check whether the polygons (> 60k instances) from layer 2, fall inside the boundaries of 1 country only (1 polygon). So, once a polygon overlaps a country boundary (= falls inside multiple countries), I need to detect them. I used the ST_CONTAINS function of PostGIS:

```
SELECT
  a.identifier, a.name, ST_Contains(c.geom, a.pol) 
FROM
  layer_polygons a, layer_countries c 
WHERE 
  ST_Contains(c.geom, a.pol) = False
```

This gives wrong 'False' values (too many False's). Any idea what can be the problem and also how I can do this the best/most efficient (current query is very slow)?

Comment: A polygon fully enclosed in country A is also not contained by country B, so your query is doing an almost complete cross join between the two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find polygons overlapped by more polygons from another layer you can use the following query.

```sql
SELECT a.identifier, a.name, count(*)
FROM layer_polygon a INNER JOIN layer_ countries c ON ST_Overlaps(a.pol, c.geom)
GROUP BY a.identifier, a.name HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Create spatial index on both layers to speed up the query.

Comment: Strange by the way that the ST_Contains function is not the solution(?). If you read the description of this function, than one would expect that this is the function that should do the trick...

Answer (score 3):

You can look for polygons partially contained by multiple country polygons, as in Zoltan's answer, or you can look for polygons that are fully contained by no country polygon.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM layer_polygons a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM layer_countries c 
  WHERE ST_Contains(c.geom, a.pol)
);
```